# I am not able to read logcat in android studio after update new version

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

After Update of android studio chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1 I am not able to debug my application due to * format. I am attaching logcat screenshot.

[image: After Update of android studio chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1 I am not able to debug my application due to * format. I am attaching logcat screenshot.]

[image]

Comment: can you share your logcat settings (to the left of logcat) and around 100 lines of your logcat content.

Comment: Please check Updated screen shots